# Calculate distinct value_1 when value_2, value_3 is equal to certain value

Tags: sql, count, case, amazon-athena

The output table looks like this let's say:

```
table : people
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   id  |  label    |   action  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |  aaaaa    |       B   |
|   1   |  aaaaa    |       B   |
|   1   |  aaaaa    |       A   |
|   2   |  aaaaa    |       B   |
|   2   |  aaaaa    |       B   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I would like to do is to count unique ids this way:

```
table : people
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|   id  |  label    |   action_A  |   action_B  |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  aaaaa    |       1     |       1     |
|   2   |  aaaaa    |       0     |       1     |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure you want only one count for action_B in the result, even though there are two occurrences?

Comment: Yes @ManfredMoser :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, label, 
   coalesce(max(1) filter (WHERE action = 'A'), 0) action_a,
   coalesce(max(1) filter (WHERE action = 'B'), 0) action_b
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, label,
       sum(case when label = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when label = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as b
from t
group by id, label;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select id, label, 
       count(distinct case when action = 'A' then action end) as action_a,
       count(distinct case when action = 'B' then action end) as action_b
from t
group by id, label;
```

OR You can just use `max()` :

```
select id, label, 
       max(case when action = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as action_a,
       max(case when action = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as action_b
from t
group by id, label;
```